# How to safely generate SQL for Camel JDBC Component

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel

I'm trying to make an insert with JDBC, and I'm looking at this example in the Camel docs: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jdbc-component.html#_using_named_parameters

But

```
.setBody("select * from projects where license = :?lic and id > :?min order by id")
```

Doesn't compile.

> The method setBody(Expression) in the type
> ProcessorDefinition is not applicable for the
> arguments (String)

You need to use simple() to shove a string into setBody(), but when I try that, the name parameters don't work. We hit the ":" and it fails at runtime.

Am I misunderstanding how to specify these name parameters or is the doc wrong? How do we safely build an sql statement in Camel?

Comment: Do you specify _useHeadersAsParameters=true_ in the url?

Comment: @eltabo, thanks, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, ensure you're specifying *useHeadersAsParameters=true* in your JDBC url, as in the example:

```
from("direct:projects")
 .setHeader("lic", constant("ASF"))
 .setHeader("min", constant(123))
 .setBody("select * from projects where license = :?lic and id > :?min order by id")
 .to("jdbc:myDataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true")
```

Answer (score 1):

`setBody(simple("...:?lic"))` works.
Take a look at the example [here](https://github.com/firstsarcasm/stack-overflow-answers/blob/master/answer-2/src/main/java/com/github/firstsarcasm/Main.java#L46)
Project compiles without any error and there is successful select result in the runtime

```
590 [main] INFO route2  - select result - [{ID=123, LICENSE=ASF}]
```